# Two Navbar rows in React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am trying to mimic this Navbar:

[image]

In React-Bootstrap,
I am thinking of having two Navbars both on top of each other, for this I have added these files:

MainNav.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function MainNav() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="md" className="justify-content-center navbar-top" fixed="top">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Minimal Blog</Navbar.Brand>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  )
}
```

Navbar.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function NavigationBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="md" className="justify-content-center navbar-top" fixed="top">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="#home">Blog</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#features">About</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  )
}
```

And in the App.tsx, I am just adding these:

```
<MainNav />
<Navbar />
```

But seems like they are super imposing on each other, I have created a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sun-se4ni?file=/src/App.tsx for Replication, any help/hints in making the desired output possible will be helpful.

EDIT 1:
I have added two Navbars, and utilised the z-index property,
but somehow, I am not able to align contents together. Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sun-se4ni?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that both of these navbars has the CSS property of `position: fixed;` so they are intertwining with each other to fix the issue you can override the CSS property by giving elements a class that would have a `position:unset` property

Comment: I have added the Navbars, but could not align them together, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In app.tsx You're importing NavigationBar but you're writing 
You don't need two navbars, you need one navbar and align the elements that you on the right.

Check these examples https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#containers

I think you need mr or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to EDIT 1, you have a container wrapped around your main nav and not in the second component. That's what is causing the alignment issue.